# Can't get viewDataField to work in MVC 3 DropDownList control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, razor

I cannot figure out why the properties won't set for this control. Here's the control code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SetViewModel[" + i + "].Value", new SelectList(@Model.Datasource.Where(c => c.listId == setting.Datasource).Select(c => c.value), "value", "description", setting.Value))
```

The error I continue to get is: **"DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'value'. "** But the property names seem to be "value" and "description." How can I confirm that I have the right property names? The Model.Datasource traces back to the ORM which has properties of "value" and "description." When I step through the code and hover over the setting.Datasource text I see properties called "value" and "description." I'm very confused. Has anyone dealt with this before? Thank you!

Comment: What's this perversion of a code in a view? How about using view models? How about using editor templates? Please promise you don't ever write something like this in a view. You would have had an excuse if this was an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application where strongly type helpers and editor templates weren't available but in ASP.NET MVC 3 this looks like a crime.

Comment: By the way, `Model` shouldn't have an `@`.

Comment: I know, I know... trust me this is painful for me too. I'm dealing with an unchangeable (I'll leave the details out) legacy data model that unfortunately calls for perversions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass a set of objects, not strings.
Remove the `Select` call.

Comment: Now that you say (type) it, it makes sense. It didn't 2 minutes ago. Thank you!